# Extracting a word from a phrase using the spaces before and after it?

Tags: java, string, extract, cpu-word

Just learning Java on my uni course and I SUCK so far!

Got to make a program that the user types in their full name in a scanner and it extracts the middle name from the string and displays it!

Example - enter "John Joe Doe" and it would extract it and with a sout would show "Joe"

Just wondering if you guys know how to extract a word from a string using the first 'space' and the last 'space'

Comment: What would be the expected output for "John Joe Jack Doe"?

Comment: Sorry I check your question again and I now know that the input is full name.

Answer (score 2):

Use string split:

**Edit**: you didn't say it's from user input. User input would be another question then. Use scanner to read user input.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class MiddleNameTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String full_Name = scanner.nextLine();
        scanner.close();
        String middleName = full_Name.split(" ")[1].trim();
        System.out.println(middleName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Much better + cleaner answer

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, i don't know if i made this aware but this is from a user keyboard input, so they would input their name, I don't know if that would change the output

Comment: @NathanielWilson Edited in the answer. You need to read your lecture notes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `indexOf` and `substring`.

Answer (score 1):

```
        String s = "John Joe Doe";
        String s1 = s.split(" ")[1];
        System.out.println(s1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String name = "John Joe Doe";
String middleName = name.split(" ")[1];
System.out.println("Middle name: " + middleName);
```

Will get the middle name 'Joe' in your example and output it, however if you need to handle more than one middle name you'll have to do something like:

```
String name = "John Joe Jack Doe";
String[] splitName = name.split(" ");
StringBuilder middleNameBuilder = new StringBuilder();
for (int i=1; i<=splitName.length-2; i++) {
    middleNameBuilder.append(splitName[i]);
    middleNameBuilder.append(" ");
}
System.out.println("Middle name: " + middleNameBuilder.toString().trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is as below:

```
String fullName = "John Joe Doe";
String[] names = fullName.split(" ");
if(names.length > 2) {
    String middelName = names[1];
    System.out.println(middleName);
} else {
    System.out.println("Please input full name");
}
```

Comment: The code of @Rehman is more elegant than mine, but my code considers a situation that the input might not be a full name (e.g., only "John"), and thus avoid ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.